What does this function do? Why is one of the variables unresolved?
This function decrypts an array of bytes to the string "crackmeYG":
+0x1610  int64_t sub_7ff7c8a11610(int64_t arg1, int128_t* arg2)

+0x1610  {
+0x1634      void var_1c8;
+0x1634      int64_t rax_1 = (__security_cookie ^ &var_1c8);
⚠️+0x1649      int128_t var_1a8;
+0x1649      __builtin_memcpy(&var_1a8, "\xc4\xff\xff\xff\x98\xff\xff\xff\xc2\xff\xff\xff\x95\xff\xff\xff\xcc\xff\xff\xff\x99\xff\xff\xff\xc6\xff\xff\xff\x82\xff\xff\xff\xf8\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x32\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x2c\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x34\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x23\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x25\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x2c\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x2e\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\xaf\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x30\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x39\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x30\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x33\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\xaf\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x23\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x33\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x2d\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x30\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x31\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x23\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x26\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x33\xff\xff\xff\xb1\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x22\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x31\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\xaf\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x33\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x32\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x2b\xff\xff\xff\x61\xff\xff\xff\x29\xff\xff\xff", 0x174);
+0x1782      int32_t var_34 = 0;
+0x1789      int64_t rdi = 0;
+0x178f      *(uint128_t*)arg2 = {0};
+0x1792      arg2[1] = 0;
+0x1796      *(uint64_t*)((char*)arg2 + 0x18) = 0xf;
+0x179e      *(uint8_t*)arg2 = 0;
+0x179e      
+0x1803      for (int64_t i = 0; i < 9; )
+0x1803      {
+0x17b5          int128_t var_188;
+0x17b5          char deobfuscated_character = (((int8_t)*(uint32_t*)(&var_1a8 + (i << 2))) - ((int8_t)*(uint32_t*)(&*(uint128_t*)((char*)var_188)[8] + (rdi << 2))));
+0x17ba          int64_t rcx = arg2[1];
+0x17be          int64_t rdx = *(uint64_t*)((char*)arg2 + 0x18);
+0x17be          
+0x17c5          if (rcx >= rdx)
+0x17e9              int64_t r8 = sub_7ff7c8a11f60(arg2, rdx, r8, deobfuscated_character);
+0x17c5          else
+0x17c5          {
+0x17cb              arg2[1] = (rcx + 1);
+0x17cf              int128_t* rax_3 = arg2;
+0x17cf              
+0x17d6              if (rdx > 0xf)
+0x17d8                  rax_3 = *(uint64_t*)arg2;
+0x17d8              
+0x17db              *(uint8_t*)((char*)rax_3 + rcx) = deobfuscated_character;
+0x17df              *(uint8_t*)(((char*)rax_3 + rcx) + 1) = 0;
+0x17c5          }
+0x17c5          
+0x17ee          i += 1;
+0x17f1          int64_t rax_4 = rdi;
+0x17f4          rdi += 1;
+0x17f4          
+0x17fb          if (rax_4 >= 0x53)
+0x17fb              rdi = 0;
+0x1803      }
+0x1803      
+0x182e      return sub_7ff7c8a124e0((rax_1 ^ &var_1c8));
+0x1610  }

I figured out the password by setting a breakpoint through each iteration of the for loop (9 is the length of crackmeYG) and just grabbing the password from a register. However, if I wanted to write a decryptor, how would I do that?
I know that var_1a8 is the encrypted array of bytes. And I know that 9 is the length of the output string. However, I don't understand HOW the loop is deobfuscating the character. I know it's subtracting two characters, but var_188 (the second character) is not defined, and binary ninja nor ida can find it. If you would like to look at the crackme, the link is here: https://crackmes.one/crackme/6757532360fa67152406b66e
Thank you for your time.
